# React Native, store information before app exits

Tags: react-native

Is this at all possible? I'm currently using `react-native-track-player` to stream audio files and I would love to be able to store the last position when my users exit the app and resume when they re-open (e.g. similar to how Spotify works)

Right now I'm tracking this info via a simple interval:

```
this.keepTime = setInterval(async () => {
  const state = await TrackPlayer.getState()
  if (state == TrackPlayer.STATE_PLAYING) {
    const ID = await TrackPlayer.getCurrentTrack()
    const position = await TrackPlayer.getPosition()
    await AsyncStorage.setItem(ID, String(position))
  }
}, 10000)
```

Problem is, I need to clear the interval when my app moves to the background or else it will crash. I would also much rather only need to call this code once as opposed to periodically if that is possible.

I know I could use headless JS on android but the app is cross platform, so my iOS user experience would be lesser.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `componentWillUnmount()` function for this.

Comment: can't believe I didn't think to try this, it's exactly what I needed. Just FYI though, answers should contain more code. This is more along the lines of a comment, for it to be a complete answer it would be best if you updated this with a more thorough code example. Thanks and welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 0):

You could add a listener to get the [App State](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/next/appstate) and then log the position when it goes to background.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    appState: AppState.currentState
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    AppState.addEventListener('change', this.handleAppStateChange);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    AppState.removeEventListener('change', this.handleAppStateChange);
    this.saveTrackPosition();
  }

  handleAppStateChange = (nextAppState) => {
    if (nextAppState.match(/inactive|background/) && this.state.appState === 'active') {
      this.saveTrackPosition();
    }
    this.setState({appState: nextAppState});
  }
  
  saveTrackPosition = () => {
    if (state == TrackPlayer.STATE_PLAYING) {
      const ID = await TrackPlayer.getCurrentTrack()
      const position = await TrackPlayer.getPosition()
      await AsyncStorage.setItem(ID, String(position))
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This fires if I manually exit the app in code but it doesn't fire if my app is swiped to close

Comment: What if you call `saveTrackPosition` when it unmounts? (see updated code).